# Using AM-GM inequality prove that $(1+\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{3})(1+\sqrt{5}) \lt 8\sqrt{30}$.

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality

It is trivial to prove that $(1+\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{3})(1+\sqrt{5}) \le 
8\sqrt{30}$  using numeric methods. For example by multiplying

$(1+\sqrt{2}) \le  3 $

$(1+\sqrt{3}) \le  3 $

$(1+\sqrt{5}) \le  4 $

We get:

$(1+\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{3})(1+\sqrt{5}) < 36$

while $8\sqrt{30} \gt 40 $ because $\sqrt{30} \gt 5 $ . However for this 
particular problem it is asked a solution using the AM-GM inequality and I am not able to find one. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use the inequality $$\frac{a+b}{2}\le \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$$ so we get
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}\times\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\times\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\le \sqrt{30}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+\sqrt 2)(1+\sqrt 3)(1+\sqrt 5)=1+\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5 + \sqrt 6 + \sqrt {10} + \sqrt {15} + \sqrt {30}$$
<strike>and thus you can use the AM-GM inequality on this</strike>

Actually I think I messed up, the AM-GM inequality goes the wrong way and the exponents don't work out. Use the Root-Mean Square - Arithmetic Mean Inequality: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality
to get that 
$$\frac{1+\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5 + \sqrt 6 + \sqrt {10} + \sqrt {15} + \sqrt {30}}{8}\leq \sqrt{\frac{72}{8}}=3\leq \sqrt{30}$$

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: It is correct. However, this seems a little too much, when you can simply say that there are $8$ terms and the largest one is $\sqrt{30}$.

Comment: @Daniel using a flamethrower to kill a mosquito?

Comment: I guess I am complaining more about the question forcing you to use a tool that is not needed at all. The OP had already seen the result is true, even a stronger result, actually.